# Detect color from image background with android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making an app on android using kotlin and there's this tricky part where the admin has to load an image to the app , when that's done the background of the layout is set to that image , the image itself has these 4 or 5 red dots spread according to a blueprint. What I want to do is to detect where those dots are then put some components over them ( Button, TextView..). I know my question is a bit complex but i hope someone could help me because I don't even know where to start with this. Thank you.

Comment: Who put that dots? You or the user? If you have ability to make an image dots then it is to get!

Comment: @Xenolion i am making the dots

Comment: So why dont you just but the dots on top of the image using a FrameLayout the user wont notice if the image are on top of the image or on the pic itself!

Comment: @Xenolion the dots are only markers to where i should put the components, actually they are not random, my mistake, they are put according to a blueprint

Comment: You can still figure out the position by that!